# Постаянный прием/отдача данных в сокетах

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Делаю для себя маленькие чат (андроид пр.) и для этого пришлось изучать сокеты. Написал приложения где сокет принимает инфу и закрывается. Мне же нужно  чтобы данные постоянна обнавлялась. Немного погуглив понял что это делается в цикли с двух сторон(на сервере и на клиенте).Сам попытался это реализовать но без успешно. Вот код клиента(при нажатие на кнопку создается и запускается класс):

```
    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        if (values[0].equals("0")){
            Toast.makeText(context , "true" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (values[0].equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(context , "false" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(values[0] == null){
            Toast.makeText(context , "null" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context , values[0] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
            txt.setText(values[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip , 5000);
            if (socket.isConnected()){
                publishProgress("0");

                while (socket.isConnected())
                {
                    pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    pr.println("message \\n");
                    pr.flush();

                    input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());

                    bf = new BufferedReader(input);
                    String answer = bf.readLine();
                    publishProgress(answer);
                    bf.close();
                    input.close();
                    pr.close();
                    socket.close();
                }
                return "okey";
            }
            else {
                publishProgress("1");
                return "net connecta";
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "ne okey";
        }
    }
}
```

без цикла все окей. Берет инфу из поток и выводит как надо один раз. В цикле же ничего не выводится. Код Сервера(PHP) при надобности могу написать.

Comment: Вы после первой итерации цикла сокет закрываете. Вот он и закрывается и следующая итерация не идёт.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб всеравно выводит данные лишь один раз

Comment: Ну... Может сервер только одно сообщение шлёт... Или сервер соединение закрывает...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перепроверил работу сервера вроде все посылает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

soket.close() вынеси за цикл иначе ты сам закрываешь соединение после первой итерации.

И небольшое review: незачем каждый раз переинициализировать pr, input и bf, вынеси их перед циклом, а закрывай после цикла.

Comment: Упоминание комментариев в вопросе не желательно. Перенесите комментарий прямо в ваш ответ.